# Rails - use object oriented "advanced"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oop

I would like to maintain my code DRY, then I want to transform this pseudo-code:

```
def aMethod
  a = aModel.find(2)
  b = a.getVariable
  a.setVariable = c
end
```

in something like this

```
def aMethod
  anotherMethod(aModel, getVariable)
end

def anotherMethod(model, var)
  a = model.find(2)
  b = a.var
  a.var = c
end
```

In my tests, seems that there is no problem for the model, but for the `getVariable` (i.e. accessing the variable of the model) it doesn't work: `undefined local variable or method`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely want to use `send`, if I understand what you're trying to do, e.g.,

```
def anotherMethod(model, var_sym)
  a = model.find(2)
  b = a.send(var_sym)
  a.send("#{var_sym}=", c)
end

anotherMethod(aModel, :getVariable)
```

<sup>*(With the caveat that I don't know what `a`, `b`, or `c` are, or should do, since they're locals in the OP.)*</sup>

Comment: I wouldn't call the argument `sym`... name it `method_name` or *something*. Calling it `sym` doesn't tell us anything about its purpose.

Comment: @meagar Originally I called it `methodSym` (a typo of `method_sym` ;) and accidentally edited it out. But I agree, although IMO the name should be coupled directly to its being something called on the model. Not convinced this is a good abstraction, but that's a different issue.

Comment: seems that is working good for retrieving the variable, as you have nice answered, but to storing a variable? seems that is not working, I must use another method as ´send´? (watch the edit at my question)

Comment: @damoiser ... Then you'd need to include the method's parameters as the last parameters to `send` as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks, working good! :) I have edited your answer to the my second question for completeness